# What is the equivalent of UIImage imageWithData for NSImage

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimage

I want to load an image into my MAC OS desktop application.  I have found plenty of documentation on how to do this on mobile iOS but how do I load the image on my desktop app since there is no UIImage(imageWithData).

```
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl"]];
productImage.image = [NSImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: `NSImage` itself has even an `initWithContentsOfURL` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`imageWithData:` is a convenience initializer for `initWithData:` in UIKIt. AppKit doesn't seem to have this, so you'll just need to use `initWithData:` like this:

```
productImage.image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

See this page for more info: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsimage/1519941-initwithdata?language=objc

Comment: Ah i see Thank you very much.